# Python как сделать автоматическую авторизацию?

Tags: python, selenium, авторизация

Сильно не ругайте, я только начинаю кодить.
Пытаюсь написать программу что бы она открывала страничку моего домашнего модема и атоматом логинилась, но при открытии странички всплывает окно где нужно ввести username и password. Обычным кодом не получается

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://192.168.1.1")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("Username")
username.send_keys("admin")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("Paasword")
password.send_keys("admin")
```

ничего не происходит, подскажите варианты для всплывающих окон. Спасибо

Comment: а вы уверены, что у элементов такие имена?

Comment: может это вообще не элементы, а basic auth, например

Comment: Если вместо обычного password в коде использовать Paasword, то ничего и никогда не получится))